# Visual Studio (Community): How do I change the program, I want VS to execute?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I'm trying already the whole time, but I still couldn't find out how to simply change the project, I want visual studio to execute. It just always starts the first project, I've made. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Project in the Solution Explorer Window and select "Set as Startup Project"

[image]